# I can't renew the Let's Encrypt certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, auto-renewing, virtualmin

I can't renew the SSL Certificate. My domain is: https://ce.oclockdt.com

I ran this command: Virtualmin -> Server Configuration -> SSL Certificate -> Let's Encrypt -> Only Update Renewal.
It produced this output: "Renewal failed due to Web-based validation failed".

My web server is Apache version 2.4.37 and runs in Rocky Linux 8.6
The version of Certbot: 1.22.0

I have consulted many questions on Stackoverflow but I can't find the solution.

I have created the directory /public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge with permissions 0777 and included an .htaccess with the content:

```
Options +Indexes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

I tried

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual -d ce.oclockdt.com
```

and this is the result:

```
Renewing an existing certificate for ce.oclockdt.com

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Create a file containing just this data:

eUd3ZH9NU76e1rEfHcbmXlXutVP4-O7YnLR-Zidl_XM.hbNn4qOrcJOUJpXJpjW6kKIYWmrSPy_O3rVxzOvqKGE

And make it available on your web server at this URL:

http://ce.oclockdt.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/eUd3ZH9NU76e1rEfHcbmXlXutVP4-O7YnLR-Zidl_XM

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Press Enter to ContinueSaving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
An unexpected error occurred:
EOFError
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

The log generated:   /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log  shows

```
And make it available on your web server at this URL:

http://ce.oclockdt.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/eUd3ZH9NU76e1rEfHcbmXlXutVP4-O7YnLR-Zidl_XM

2023-06-14 11:17:46,909:DEBUG:certbot._internal.error_handler:Encountered exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certbot/_internal/auth_handler.py", line 85, in handle_authorizations
    resps = self.auth.perform(achalls)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certbot/_internal/plugins/manual.py", line 186, in perform
    self._perform_achall_manually(achall, i == last_dns_achall)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certbot/_internal/plugins/manual.py", line 234, in _perform_achall_manually
    display_util.notification(msg, wrap=False, force_interactive=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certbot/display/util.py", line 76, in notification
    force_interactive=force_interactive, decorate=decorate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certbot/_internal/display/obj.py", line 95, in notification
    util.input_with_timeout("Press Enter to Continue")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certbot/_internal/display/util.py", line 67, in input_with_timeout
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

This is the content of  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf :

```
<VirtualHost 162.19.89.212:80 [2001:41d0:306:2cd4::]:80>
    ServerName ce.oclockdt.com
    ServerAlias www.ce.oclockdt.com
    ServerAlias mail.ce.oclockdt.com
    ServerAlias webmail.ce.oclockdt.com
    ServerAlias admin.ce.oclockdt.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ce/public_html/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/ce.oclockdt.com_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/ce.oclockdt.com_access_log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/ce/cgi-bin/
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php5 index.htm index.html
    <Directory /home/ce/public_html/public>
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ce/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/fcgiwrap/167161024797448.sock/socket|fcgi://localhost
        ProxyFCGISetEnvIf true SCRIPT_FILENAME "/home/ce%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.ce.oclockdt.com
    RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known)(.*) https://ce.oclockdt.com:20000/ [R]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.ce.oclockdt.com
    RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known)(.*) https://ce.oclockdt.com:10000/ [R]
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php7.2
    RemoveHandler .php8.0
    RemoveHandler .php8.1
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/php-fpm/167161024797448.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 162.19.89.212:443 [2001:41d0:306:2cd4::]:443>
    ServerName ce.oclockdt.com
    ServerAlias www.ce.oclockdt.com
    ServerAlias mail.ce.oclockdt.com
    ServerAlias webmail.ce.oclockdt.com
    ServerAlias admin.ce.oclockdt.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ce/public_html/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/ce.oclockdt.com_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/ce.oclockdt.com_access_log combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/ce/cgi-bin/
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php5 index.htm index.html
    <Directory /home/ce/public_html/public>
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ce/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/fcgiwrap/167161024797448.sock/socket|fcgi://localhost
        ProxyFCGISetEnvIf true SCRIPT_FILENAME "/home/ce%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.ce.oclockdt.com
    RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known)(.*) https://ce.oclockdt.com:20000/ [R]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.ce.oclockdt.com
    RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known)(.*) https://ce.oclockdt.com:10000/ [R]
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php7.2
    RemoveHandler .php8.0
    RemoveHandler .php8.1
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/php-fpm/167161024797448.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1
    </FilesMatch>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/virtualmin/167161024797448/ssl.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/virtualmin/167161024797448/ssl.key
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/virtualmin/167161024797448/ssl.ca
</VirtualHost>
```

I also restarted the server.

Well, I think that the error is that Let's Encrypt can't create the test file in  /public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge  but this directory has permissions. ¿Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I used the command:

> sudo certbot certonly -d ce.oclockdt.com

I have done it from command.com on Windows with SSH. So I have seen that the system waits for me to choose 1 or 2. I have selected option 2 and everything is ok.